# Compile error from cmake build of OpenCV on Windows 10 Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cmake

I downloaded `opencv_contrib=master.zip` and `opencv-4.0.0.zip` from GitHUB, uncompressed and ran CMake(cmake gui) configured, and checked the appropriate boxes and browsed for the `opeencv_contrib_master/modules` folder that should  generate the solution which I tried to build ALL+_BUILD with Visual Studio Community 2017.

But I get a 3 compile errors:

> C2872 'TonemapDurand:ambiguous symbol open_python2 pyopencv_generated_funcs.h 29771

I don't want to change the source code if I don't need to, but I don't know what to do?

Comment: You probably need to check OpenCV dependencies. If you are using python, check that you are installing it in the VS installer. If not, set BUILD_opencv_python to OFF

Answer (score 0):

If you can build opencv without contrib then you might try this solution:

```
path .../opencv_contrib/modules
```

with forward slash '/' not ''